# NoSuchMethodError when using realm.io in a library

Tags: java, android, realm

I transferred the model classes of my Android app inlcuding realm.io functions into a library following the advices described in the realm.io Java docs section [Sharing schemas](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas).
I'm facing a NoSuchMethodError when my app (indirectly) calls realm.io methods which are in the the library.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method copyOrUpdate(Lio/realm/Realm;Lmy/package/structure/MyModelClass;ZLjava/util/Map;)Lmy/package/structure/MyModelClass; in class Lio/realm/MyModelClassRealmProxy; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.realm.MyModelClassRealmProxy' appears in /data/user/0/my.name.space/files/.jrebel/load-dexes/bundle3/classes.zip) 
  at io.realm.MyModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(MyModuleMediator.java:98)
  at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1164)
  at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:757)
```

Here is how my library looks like:

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.1'        
  }
}
```

**build.gradle (library module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-rules.pro')
    }
}
...
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

I used [this snippet](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-realm.pro) as a template

```
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class * { *; }
-keep my.package.MyModelClass
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

**MyModule.java**

```
package my.package;

import io.realm.annotations.RealmModule;

@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class MyModule { }
```

**MyRealm.java**

```
package my.package;

import ...

public class MyRealm {
    private final RealmConfiguration realmConfig;

    public MyRealm(Context context) {
        realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("name.of.my.config")
                .modules(new MyModule())
                .build();
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {
        return Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    }
}
```

**MyModelClass.class**

```
package my.package;

import ...

public class MyModelClass extends RealmObject {

  public void save(Context context) {
    Realm realm = new MyRealm(context).getRealm();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(MyModelClass.this);
        }
    });
    realm.close();
  }
}
```

In my actual app I call something like this which is causing the Exception:

**MyActivity.java**

```
// ...
MyModelClass c = new MyModelClass();
c.save(context);
```

The code above was working well when everything was in the app project.

Am I missing something general?
Is there something more I need to consider regarding the proguard settings of the lib?
May JRebel cause this kind of problem?

Comment: JRebel could easily cause this problem, but I'd also consider updating to v1.1.1. It shouldn't have any breaking changes, and it might even fix this problem if you're lucky enough.

Comment: Does it work if you disable JRebel?

Comment: I also had a similar problem once when I accidentally left an old `compile` dependency of Realm in along with the new Realm plugin.

Comment: Good news: not using JRebel did the trick. Better news: using JRebel plugin 1.3.6 works fine as well. @EpicPandaForce : thanks for the advice

Comment: Getting same error. Used Realm in the exact same way in library. I am not using JRebel

Comment: @tacticurv Any chance of Realm version mismatch?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No I am using the same version 3.4.0. Its set in the project gradle file only once. In the library gradle file only line related to realm is apply plugin: 'realm-android'

Answer (score 2):

I think you might not be using it correctly, I will suggest that you see a full working example like the one they reference are the end of that [Sharing Schemas](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas) link. The link is to this repository [full working example of realm lib and app](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample). I would suggest that you take a look at the [Zoo class](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/moduleExample/library/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/librarymodules/Zoo.java) from the library, the methods are the only thing exposed to the application as you can see [in the app's activity here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/moduleExample/app/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/appmodules/ModulesExampleActivity.java) (line 148 and downwards).

I think this was just a confusion on your part, because from what I understood you are calling your library class and using it like it was a Realm instance for that activity context which is not the case. Hope this can steer you in the right path!

Basically you simply create an instance based on you configuration so you don't need to pass a context there.

Answer (score 1):

This happens with JRebel, I would suggest you try with the latest version of it if the issue still persists try not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message as the original post.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method copyOrUpdate(Lio/realm/Realm;Lmy/package/structure/MyModelClass;ZLjava/util/Map;)Lmy/package/structure/MyModelClass; in class Lio/realm/MyModelClassRealmProxy; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.realm.MyModelClassRealmProxy' appears in /data/user/0/my.name.space/files/.jrebel/load-dexes/bundle3/classes.zip) 
  at io.realm.MyModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(MyModuleMediator.java:98)
  at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1164)
  at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:757)`

But my problem was a different one. I had one Realm module in a library and an additional Realm module in my app. Unfortunately both modules contain an entity with the same class name (but in different packages). 
The code generation for realm creates only only one `io.realm.<classname>RealmProxy` class. Because of that I got the above mentioned exception.

The solution is quite simply: Just rename of the entities.